# PHP: How to set timezone for an offset DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to create a DateTime object offset from the present with a specific timezone. It works for `'today'`, or an absolute value like `'2017-07-16 00:00:00'`, but if I try an offset, like `'+1 sundays'` it always has a timezone of "S".

```
$dtz = date_default_timezone_get();//"America/Vancouver"
$now = new \DateTime('today', new \DateTimeZone($dtz));
$sunday = new \DateTime('+1 sundays', new \DateTimeZone($dtz));
$later = new \DateTime('2357-04-13', new \DateTimeZone($dtz));
$tz1 = $now->getTimezone()->getName();//"America/Vancouver"
$tz2 = $sunday->getTimezone()->getName();//"S"
$tz3 = $later->getTimezone()->getName();//"America/Vancouver"
```

How should I do this?

Comment: `+1` is not a timezone. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to add 1 hour to the time, then do that. If you want to set a different timezone, then do that instead.

Comment: @TomLord I was trying to set the date as next Sunday. It actually does that, but with the wrong timezone. Likewise, `+2 sundays` gives the Sunday after next, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to DateTime should be a valid date/time string. It even takes null when using timezone as second parameter.

'+1 sundays' is not under the category of valid date/time string. Check the complete list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Below should work -

```
$sunday = $now->modify('+1 sundays');
echo $sunday->getTimezone()->getName();//"America/Vancouver"
```

Comment: This does create `$sunday` with the proper timezone, but it also modifies `$now` to be next Sunday. It looks like I have to first create $sunday as a new DateTime, then run `$sunday->modify('+1 sundays');`